# .NET Core 2.0 dotnet restore: command line vs. visual studio

Tags: visual-studio-2017, asp.net-core-2.0

With VS2017, latest update:

if you create a .NET core 2.0 project, it will look like this:

[image]

When trying to do a restore from VS:

[image]

Absolutely nothing happens...

On the other hand typing:

> dotnet restore

fixes the problem.

Is the VS tooling still behind and broken after all this time, or am I missing something?

Comment: As far as I know, the VS will auto Restoring NuGet packages after the application created. I have also created a test demo on my side, it could restore well. I suggest you could open the output window to check if it show any error message. Image like this:https://i.stack.imgur.com/lTHiM.png

Comment: Mine doesn't output anything at all; I'm with VS Enterprise 15.5.5; in fact it doesn't do anything, there is no wait time, etc as if I never clicked